# Why isn't my Facebook Pixel code being rendered?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Does anyone know why my Facebook Pixel code is appearing at the bottom of my page, as in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if you are missing a < in your first Facebook Pixel Code comment, and the result is it rendering as a text string.  The first comment should read:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

it requires modifications other than header and footer, for complete install able code you can go to opencart website and download module developed by purchase theme.